# integration with payment processer

Tags: payment-processor

I'm bidding on a redesign of an existing Joomla site that requires tight integration with CiciCRM. The client wishes to move from PayPal to an online merchant account.

Is there a list of preferred payment processors to use with CiviCRM?

thanks,
david

Answer (score 2):

Ginkgo Street Labs has collated four of the most common processors into one post:  [Evaluating Payment Processor Options](http://ginkgostreet.com/content/evaluating-payment-processor-options)

For a larger comparison see: [Payment Processors](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/86213600)

For general instructions see: [Contributions - Payment Processors](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/contributions/payment-processors/)